# Error when I try to draw Voronoi Polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

I have an error when I try to densify polygon verticles through "Densify by interval" and draw Voronoi polygons. The error appears on various polygons. For example, if a small polygon is densified at intervals of 10 m (30 m there is no error). If a large polygon is densified at intervals of 50 m. Does anyone know what's going on here? I need to densify polygon vertices to build accurate Voronoi polygons.

I'm using QGIS 3.34. There are no errors in input layers.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Fix geometries on the input layer? Other things you can try is buffering with a very small distance, and or Snap points to grid

Comment: Yes, I've tried. I have no geometry errors. May be there is error in Voronoi algorithm?

Comment: @redhat It is possible. However, in QGIS 3.28 Voronoi polygons works for me up to ~2cm vertex density. I googled a bit and it seems that multipart geometries may cause problems with Voronoi, you can check if that's the case. If you can provide sample data, people could try to reproduce the error, that would help determining whether the error source is in the algorithm, settings, data, etc.

Comment: Another thing you can try is simplifying the geometries

Comment: @crafter6029 I'v loaded it here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RVM_l-6qabIcK6z0czrxkdd0P--v0WnC?usp=sharing It's a source polygon. I densify it with 10 meters, then extract verticles, try to run Voronoi polygons and got an error. But if I densify it with 30 meters it ok. And I have another polygon but greater that this and I can't densify it at all. I think it is one polygon, not multigeometry

Comment: @redhat I get an access denied message. Could you set the access to 'anyone with the link can open' or similar?

Comment: Yes. It's a big polygon that I can't densify https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BJrOPtib3I53hpWzI30lULKDakVLjetD?usp=sharing And here a smaller polygon that I cant densify more that 30 meters https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RVM_l-6qabIcK6z0czrxkdd0P--v0WnC?usp=sharing

Comment: Tested it on QGIS 3.28, different machine than the previous test. 1) I had no problems densifying either polygons to 10 m, extracting the vertices and generating Voronoi polygons. Voronoi takes quite some time for the big one though. 2) Your polygons are in fact multipart; this doesn't seem to cause the current issue, but best keep it in mind, might become relevant later in your work. 3) I suggest you install QGIS 3.28, and try the processing there. If it works, that would point to a 3.34-specific issue, if it doesn't, then it might be something in your setup.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it at 3.28